# PL/SQL: nested table with id's and create view

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i've created tables, linked through the nested table inside one of them:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  NAME VARCHAR(150) ,
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
) ;

CREATE TYPE A_LIST IS TABLE OF integer;

CREATE TABLE B (
  NAME VARCHAR(150),
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  LIST A_LIST 
) NESTED TABLE LIST STORE AS LIST_TABLE;
```

now I need to CREATE VIEW to show data from table B with nested data from A. Its something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ff OF B, A AS 
    SELECT N.name, N.LIST
               CAST( MULTISET (
                 ....
               )AS TYPE_FILM_LIST)
          FROM B N;
```

but i'm stuck in that dots(

Comment: try this cast( multiset (select LIST from B where condition)as type_film_list)  in your query. If it is wrong please post your view code.

Comment: I need to get output like 
"name {name, name, name}"
where goes data from table B and then (nested) data from A. How to do it?

Comment: Column "B.LIST" is collection of id's from table A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join the tables B and A based on nested ID's - here an example.

Some test data

```
 insert into b
 values ('x',1, A_LIST(1,2,3));

 insert into a values ('A1',1);
 insert into a values ('A2',2);
 insert into a values ('A3',3);
```

The main step is the join of the table B with the nested table `from b, table(b.list)`  The nested ID is returned as `COLUMN_VALUE` ; rest is simple join

```
 select b.id, b.name, a.name a_name, a.id a_id   from b, table(b.list) ba, a
 where ba.column_value = a.id;
```

result

```
         ID SUBSTR(B.NAME,1,5) A_NAME       A_ID        
         ---------- ------------------ ------ ----------  
         1 x                  A1              1           
         1 x                  A2              2  
         1 x                  A3              3
```

Comment: Ahh, it appeared so heavy for me. It worked with my data! And this amount of simplicity I could understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
create type record_for_a is object( a varchar2(150), id number);
create type l_record_for_a is table of record_for_a;


select table_b.name, table_b.id, 
 cast( multiset (select record_for_a(aa.name,aa.id) from a aa, table(table_b.list) bb where aa.id = bb.column_value) as l_record_for_a)  
 neste_col_a
 from 
b table_b;
```

Comment: you created a record for A, but i need to connect TABLES